# custom error handler throw error : Cannot read property 'get' of undefined ( Injector )

Tags: angular, typescript, error-handling

I am building a custom error handler in angular 4 to handle different kind of application error with error interceptor

create a base class( *app-error.ts* ) and other classes ( for eg. to handle 403 errors create class *access-denied.ts* ) which extend this base class.

in the base class have injected a service `toastrService` and I want to display custom message from the child class BUT it gives the error on

Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

thisissue is related to OOPS concept. I do not understand how to get override parent method or call with my custom argument.

TS v 2.3.3
angular v 4.3.4

#### app.module.ts

```
providers: [
{ provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: AppErrorHandler }
]
```

NOTE: AppErrorHandler class is completely different than AppError which extend angular ErorHandler interface which handle system errors.

#### error-interceptor

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpResponse, HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpErrorResponse
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';

import {
    AuthFail,
    BadInput,
    NotFoundError,
    ServerError,
    AppError,
    AccessDenied,
} from '../shared/errors';
import { AuthenticationService } from './../authentication/authentication.service';


@Injectable()
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    private auth: AuthenticationService;
    constructor(private router: Router, private injector: Injector) { }
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        const auth = this.injector.get(AuthenticationService);
        return next.handle(req).catch((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                if (err.status === 401) {
                    return Observable.throw(new AuthFail(err.error));
                }
                if (err.status === 400) {
                    return Observable.throw(new BadInput(err.error));
                }
                if (err.status === 404) {
                    return Observable.throw(new NotFoundError());
                }
                if (err.status === 403) {
                    return Observable.throw(new AccessDenied());
                }
                return Observable.throw(new AppError(err));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

#### access-denied.ts

```
import { AppError } from './app-error';
export class AccessDenied extends AppError {
    constructor(public originalError?: any) {
        super();
        console.log('inside acces denied constructor');
        // super.handleError("superrrrr"); // this also doesn't work
    }

    public handleError(): void {
        console.log('handleError: ', );
        super.handleError("Access denined error occured");
    }
}
```

#### app-error.ts

```
import { Inject, Injector } from "@angular/core";

import { ToastrService } from "ngx-toastr";

export class AppError {
    toastrService: ToastrService;
    constructor(public originalError?: any, private injector?: Injector) {
        this.toastrService = this.injector.get(ToastrService);
    }

    // NOTE: using getter seems impossible to access in child so add the same in constructor
    // get toastrService(): ToastrService {
    //  return this.injector.get(ToastrService);
    // }

    public handleError(msg: string): void {
        this.toastrService.error(`Error Message: ${msg}`,
            "Error", {
                closeButton: true,
                timeOut: 5000,
                onActivateTick: true
            }
        );
    }

}
```

gives error

---

```
core.es5.js:1020 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined 
    at AccessDenied.AppError (app-error.ts:8) 
    at new AccessDenied (access-denied.ts:6)  
    at CatchSubscriber.eval [as selector] (error.interceptor.ts:61) 
    at CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:105)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http.es5.js:1739)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:3881)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:496)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AccessDenied` incorrectly extends `AppError`. `super()` results in `injector` being undefined, and `injector` shouldn't be optional in `AppError` constructor, because it is required.

It could be fixed by making a parameter obligatory:

```
constructor(private injector: Injector, public originalError?: any) {
    this.toastrService = this.injector.get(ToastrService);
}
```

The constructor can be omitted in `AccessDenied`. And should be instantiated like `new AccessDenied(injector)`.

The real problem here is that `AppError` does the work it isn't supposed to to. Considering that it just contains the error that can be later determined with `err instanceof AppError`, it shouldn't do side effects that are currently done in `handleError`.

The logic in `handleError` could be moved to a method in `ToastrService` or separate error service that accepts an instance of `AppError`. If there's a need to provide default message for error type like `Access denied error occurred`, `AppError` can have public property that contains the message.

Comment: Thank you for this valuable approach and solution.  "constructor in AccessDenied omitted" > than where to define a custom message for the access denied error? and where to write `new AccessDenied(injector)` ?

Comment: You could make custom message a field, like `public message = 'Access denied error occurred'`. It's `Observable.throw(new AccessDenied(injector))`. But again, error classes shouldn't handle themselves.

Comment: than how to handle the error? can you show some code how to achive ?

Comment: Could be placed in ToastrService, something like `handleError(err: AppError) { this.error(err.message, ...) }`. Then you don't need multiple `return Observable.throw`, just a single `toastService.handleError(err); return Observable.throw(err)` at the end of `if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {...}`. Hope you got the idea.

Comment: you mean inside err.interceptor.ts ; if i do not add multiple than how do we distinguish the error? this is lil bit confusing. although my work done by I have to send injector from interceptor to new AccessDenied() and than again call super(injector) . let me share the code which is working right now

Comment: see this code is working fine but there is too much repetition of code http://collabedit.com/mcj3t

Comment: I'm not sure if you see the changes in your link. Here's what I mean, see the interceptor. http://collabedit.com/2jxyq

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166399/discussion-between-pro-mean-and-estus).

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to inject the ToastrService into an error class. This isn't possible because Angular isn't instanciating the object for you so it can't inject the dependencies. If you insist on doing it this way, you'd have to pass the ToastrService into each AppError yourself.

I suggest creating a custom ErrorHandler that looks to see if the error is an instance of AppError and then using the ToastrService to show a toast.

Roughly something like this (not tested):

**app-error.ts**

```
import { Inject, Injector } from "@angular/core";

import { ToastrService } from "ngx-toastr";

export class AppError {
    constructor(public message?: string, public title?: string) { }

}
```

**access-denied.ts**

```
import { AppError } from './app-error';
export class AccessDenied extends AppError {
    constructor(message?: string, title?: string) {
        super(message, title);
    }
}
```

**app-error.handler.ts**

```
import { ErrorHandler, Inject, Injector, Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { ToastrService } from "ngx-toastr";
import { AppError } from './app-error';

@Injectable()
export class AppErrorHandler extends ErrorHandler {

    constructor(@Inject(Injector) private injector: Injector) {
        super(true);
    }

    // Need to get ToastrService from injector rather than constructor injection to avoid cyclic dependency error
    private get toastrService(): ToastrService {
        return this.injector.get(ToastrService);
    }

    public handleError(error: any): void {
        if (error instanceof AppError) {
            this.toastrService.error(
                error.message,
                error.title,
                {
                    closeButton: true,
                    timeOut: 5000,
                    onActivateTick: true
                }
            );
        }

        super.handleError(error);
    }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  // Your imports, declarations, bootstrap, etc.
  // ...

  providers: [
    // Other providers...

    {
      provide: ErrorHandler,
      useClass: AppErrorHandler
    }
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but there is interceptor also in my case. error first react to error interceptor and it redirects to the respective class ( in my case AccessDenied class which extends AppError ) based on the error.status so AppErrorHandler never comes into the picture? I am sure I am doing something wrong but don't know what?

Comment: Any errors that get thrown in the HttpClient observable (that you don't catch) should be caught by the application's error handler (normally Angular's default ErrorHandler). If you replace it with AppErrorHandler, it can handle any error thrown by your app