# Injecting router in Global Error Handler: Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a scenario in Angular 5 where I need to redirect page based on Error Handler I defined in each class.
These are my error classes.

```
export class AppError {
  constructor(
    public originalError?: any,
    executeParent?: boolean
  ) {
    if (executeParent) {
      console.log(originalError);
    }
  }
}

export class NotFoundError extends AppError {
  constructor(originalError) {
    super(originalError);
    console.log(this);
  }
}
```

and I am using them in services like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class AccountService {
  account: Account;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  fetch () {
    return this.http.get(ENDPOINT.ACCOUNT).catch((error: Response) => {
      if (error.status === 404) {
        return Observable.throw(new NotFoundError(error));
      }
      return Observable.throw(new AppError(error));
    });
  }
}
```

Now I need to do something like this

```
export class AppError {
  private router: Router;
  private store: StoreService;

  constructor(
    public originalError?: any,
    executeParent?: boolean
  ) {
    if (executeParent) {
      if (this.store.errorMessage.getValue().code) {
        log.print('ErrorCode: ', this.store.errorMessage.getValue().code);
        this.router.navigate(['/errorPage']);
      }
      console.log(originalError);
    }
  }
}
```

But it's not letting me because router and store are not defined. I can't define a new instance because I need a reference to the store.

I don't want to use this in the constructor because I'll have to pass this value from so many lower levels. I want to keep my class signature simple and straight. because I need to add more types of errors here and I can't pass store and router in such long hierarchies.

Comment: Exactly same problem as here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49148781/custom-error-handler-throw-error-cannot-read-property-get-of-undefined-inj . Error class isn't an appropriate place for side effects.